# Xamarin Account menu disappeared after VS2017 15.5.2 Update

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

The Xamarin Account menu disappeared after VS2017 15.5.2 Update (using Enterprise here)

[image]

Now I don't have it anymore and can't find it!

Thanks

Comment: what version of visual studio you have? Enterprise, Pro, Education ... ?

Comment: using the Enterprise version.

Comment: Please check the installer and make sure you enable all Xamarin components in there.

Comment: I will check, but this happened to a friend too in different PC, but I will double check here. thanks

Comment: Xamarin accounts are obsolete. What are you trying to access?

Comment: oh.. so this is the reason,, and found this now also
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97295/how-do-i-sign-in-to-xamarin-account-with-visual-studio-community-2017-for-mac

Comment: @SushiHangover do the login to the xamarin account or Logout to use another user.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro Components are being deprecated, you should start using the Nuget packages directly.

Comment: But what is the relation between xamarin account and Nuget package?